# BibLaTeX: Customizing backreferences

Tags: biblatex, back-referencing

I am trying to switch from Natbib to BibLaTeX.
In Natbib (via hyperref), I have the following customization for backreferences:

```
\renewcommand*{\backref}[1]{}
\renewcommand*{\backrefalt}[4]{%
\ifcase #1 %
(Not cited.)%
\or
Cited on page~#2.%
\else
Cited on pages~#2.%
\fi}
\renewcommand*{\backrefsep}{, }
\renewcommand*{\backreftwosep}{ and~}
\renewcommand*{\backreflastsep}{, and~}
```

I want do the same customization in BibLatex.
The following will get halways:

```
\usepackage[backref=true]{biblatex}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
    backrefpage = {Cited on page},
    backrefpages = {Cited on pages},
}
```

What I need help with it is:

1. Add (Not cited.) to all entries added via \nocite{}.
2. Properly format the page list, e.g. "Cited on pages 1,2,3,4, and 5.". --- Now it outputs  "Cited on pages 1,2,3,4,5.".

Edit:

---

### Solution (created from the reply by @Guido):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=false, pdfborder={0 0 0}}    

\usepackage[backend=bibtex,backref=true]{biblatex}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  backrefpage = {Cited on page},
  backrefpages = {Cited on pages},
}
\renewbibmacro{pageref}{%
  \iflistundef{pageref}
    {\printtext[parens]{Not Cited}} 
    {%
     \printtext[parens]{\ifnumgreater{\value{pageref}}{1}   
       {\bibstring{backrefpages}\ppspace} 
       {\bibstring{backrefpage}\ppspace}
       \printlist [pageref][-\value{listtotal}]{pageref}}}}    

\DeclareListFormat{pageref}{%
     % == 2 references
    \ifthenelse{\value{liststop} < 3}{\ifthenelse{\value{listcount}<\value{liststop}}{\hyperpage{#1} and }{\hyperpage{#1}}} %
    { % > 2 references
        \ifthenelse{\value{listcount}<\value{liststop}}
          {\hyperpage{#1}\addcomma\addspace}
          {\ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststop}}
            {and \hyperpage{#1}}
            {}%
          }%
    }%  
}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@article{zero,title= {Tile 0}}
@article{one,title= {Tile 1}}
@article{two,title= {Tile 2}}
@article{three,title= {Tile 3}},
}            

\end{filecontents} 
\bibliography{mybib}
\begin{document}            

\nocite{zero}
\cite{one}
\cite{two}
\cite{three}            

\newpage
\cite{two}
\cite{three}
\newpage
\cite{three}            

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Produces:

> [1] “Tile 0”. In: (). (Not cited).
>
> [2] “Tile 1”. In: () (Cited on page 1).
>
> [3] “Tile 2”. In: () (Cited on pages 1 and 2).
>
> [4] “Tile 3”. In: () (Cited on pages 1, 2, and 3).

Comment: It will be much easier to help when you provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). As people keep saying, solving problems can be fun but setting them up rarely is!

Comment: Thanks for this cool answer. However I wanted to get the rid off this Oxford Comma (just before the "and"). If you also want that: see here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/257246/74646

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The backrefs are stored in the `pageref` list. Thus you can use `\DeclareListFormat` control how the backrefs are formatted.

Here is a possible definition to  achieve what you want:

```
\DeclareListFormat{pageref}{%
\ifthenelse{\value{listcount}<\value{liststop}}
  {#1\addcomma\addspace}
  {\ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststop}}
    {and #1}
    {}%
  }%
}
```

To cover the case of entries not cited, one has to modify the `pageref` bibmacro

```
\renewbibmacro{pageref}{%
  \iflistundef{pageref}
    {\printtext[parens]{Not Cited}} 
    {%
     \printtext[parens]{\ifnumgreater{\value{pageref}}{1}   
       {\bibstring{backrefpages}\ppspace} 
       {\bibstring{backrefpage}\ppspace}
       \printlist [pageref][-\value{listtotal}]{pageref}}}}
```

With the provided MWE it produces:

[image]

Comment: Thank for the reply, this solves problem (2)! This does however not solve the issue with \nocite, problem (1).

Comment: @user7726 edited the solution to cover problem (1).

Comment: Thanks for this cool answer. However I wanted to get the rid off this Oxford Comma (just before the "and"). If you also want that: see here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/257246/74646

Answer (score 1):

If one doesn't want to get a comma before last element using BibLaTeX, the definition proposed by Guido and OP should be modified:

```
\DeclareListFormat{pageref}{%
    \ifthenelse{\value{listcount}=1}%
        {\hyperpage{#1}}%
        {\ifthenelse{\value{listcount}<\value{liststop}}%
            {\addcomma\addspace\hyperpage{#1}}%
            {\ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststop}}%
                {\addspace{}and\addspace\hyperpage{#1}}{}%
            }%
        }%
}%
```

The exemplary output will be:

> (Cited on pages 1 and 2)
>
> (Cited on pages 1, 2 and 3)

BTW, hello to the TeX.stackexchange community!

Comment: Note that one can also let `biblatex` do the work and decide whether or not to use a Oxford comma via `\finallistdelim`, see [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/257257/35864) for details.

Comment: This solution is nice. For some reason, @moewe, `\finallistdelim` could not produce correct output.