# How to do IF counter+1 < ... THEN nicely for beautifying Biblatex backreference

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, counters

This article and snippet: [BibLaTeX: Customizing backreferences](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208678/biblatex-customizing-backreferences)

Produces:

> [4] “Tile 3”. In: () (Cited on pages 1, 2, and 3).

Now I want to get the rid off this last comma (Oxford comma) after the 2, so I modified it as described below (counter+1, if compare, counter-1) and this does the trick:

> [4] “Tile 3”. In: () (Cited on pages 1, 2 and 3).

**HOWEVER**, I think this is not the **nicest** way to do it (increment counter, compare, decrement). Just out curosity, is there a nicer possibility e.g:

> \ifthenelse{\value{mycounter}+1}{............}

??

**Change to get rid off the Oxford comma:** (see after comment line "if before second last ref then add ", " else " " ")

```
\DeclareListFormat{pageref}{%
 % == 2 references
\ifthenelse{\value{liststop} < 3}
{\ifthenelse{\value{listcount}<\value{liststop}}{\hyperpage{#1} and }{\hyperpage{#1}}} %
{ % > 2 references
    \ifthenelse{\value{listcount}<\value{liststop}}
      {\hyperpage{#1}%
        \addtocounter{listcount}{1}%
        % if before second last ref then add ", " else " "
     \ifthenelse{\value{listcount}<\value{liststop}}%
     {\addcomma\addspace}{\addspace}%
    \addtocounter{listcount}{-1}%
      }
      {\ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststop}}
        {and \hyperpage{#1}}
        {}%
      }%
}%
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One very clean solution is to make the list format use the two command `multilistdelim` and `finallistdelim` at the appropriate places in `list:plain`. The Oxford comma can be dropped by redefining `\finalandcomma` and `\finalandsemicolon`.

Finally, for this to work, you will have to call `backrefstyle=none`.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,backref=true,backrefstyle=none]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\NewBibliographyString{notcited}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  notcited     = {not cited},
  backrefpage  = {cited on page},
  backrefpages = {cited on pages},
}

\DefineBibliographyExtras{english}{%
  \let\finalandcomma\empty
  \let\finalandsemicolon\empty
}

\renewbibmacro*{list:plain}{%
  \ifnumgreater{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststart}}
    {\ifboolexpr{
       test {\ifnumless{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststop}}}
       or
       test \ifmoreitems
     }
       {\printdelim{multilistdelim}}
       {\printdelim{finallistdelim}}}
    {}}

\renewbibmacro{pageref}{%
  \printtext[parens]{%
    \bibsentence
    \iflistundef{pageref}
      {\bibstring{notcited}}
      {\ifnumgreater{\value{pageref}}{1}
         {\bibstring{backrefpages}\ppspace}
         {\bibstring{backrefpage}\ppspace}%
       \printlist[pageref][-\value{listtotal}]{pageref}}}}


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{zero,  title = {Tile 0}}
@article{one,   title = {Tile 1}}
@article{two,   title = {Tile 2}}
@article{three, title = {Tile 3}}    
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}

\nocite{zero}
\cite{one}
\cite{two}
\cite{three}

\newpage
\cite{two}
\cite{three}
\newpage
\cite{three}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: 4 “Tile 3”. In: () (Cited on pages 1, 2 and 3).]

Comment: To be honest, I don't understand why `list:plain` isn't defined like that in the first place.